# Why are my CSS cards stacking, instead of floating next to each other?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I can't figure it out. Seems to work fine in Codepen but when I transfer to my site template, it breaks... CSS and HTML below. Could anybody please help? I'm not sure if it's something in the master template which might be doing it, but it right now I'm not able to check that without contacting support.

```
.gc-homepage-links-section {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  display: grid;
  
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  
  @media (min-width: 30em) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 60em) {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}

.gc-homepage-card {
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 110%;
}
  
  gc-homepage-article {
    padding: 30px;
    flex: 1;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  h3.homepage-h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #154ae5;
  }
  
.gc-homepage-cards {
    line-height: 1.8em;
}
```

```
<div class="gc-homepage-links-section">
<div class="gc-homepage-card">
      <gc-homepage-article>
        <h3 class="gc-homepage-h3">Headline here</h3>
        <ul class="gc-homepage-cards">
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>Hello again</li>
                    <li>Hello again</li>
                    <li>Hello again</li>
                    <li>Hello again</li>
          </ul>
      </gc-homepage-article>
</div>
  <div class="gc-homepage-card">
      <gc-homepage-article>
        <h3 class="gc-homepage-h3">Another headline</h3>
        <ul class="gc-homepage-cards">
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>Hello again</li>
                    <li>Hello again</li>
                    <li>Hello again</li>
                    <li>Hello again</li>
          </ul>
      </gc-homepage-article>
</div>
  <div class="gc-homepage-card">
      <gc-homepage-article>
        <h3 class="gc-homepage-h3">Good To Know</h3>
        <ul class="gc-homepage-cards">
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>Hello again</li>
                    <li>Hello again</li>
                    <li>Hello again</li>
                    <li>Hello again</li>
          </ul>
      </gc-homepage-article>
</div>
  <div class="gc-homepage-card">
      <gc-homepage-article>
        <h3 class="gc-homepage-h3">Get Involved</h3>
        <ul class="gc-homepage-cards">
          <li>Hello</li>
          <li>Hello again</li>
                    <li>Hello again</li>
                    <li>Hello again</li>
                    <li>Hello again</li>
          </ul>
      </gc-homepage-article>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Media queries must wrap _rule sets_, not specific properties.

Answer (score 1):

You did media queries wrong, they should be outside the class like so:

```css
@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .gc-homepage-links-section {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 60em) {
  .gc-homepage-links-section {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
```